Purpose of Generating Function
I am learning about generating functions, and I have question about how to effectively use them.

The number of integer partitions of $r$ into odd parts is $(1+x+x^2+...)(1+x^3+x^6+...)(1+x^5+x^{10}+...)...$

I understand the expression above, but I am confused as to what the purpose of doing this is. Either way, we still need to manually determine the coefficient of $x^i$ by determining the odd partitions of $i$, so why not just do that from the start? What is the point of making this generating function?

I assume your quotation environment forgot the phrase "the $x^r$ coefficient in" or its abbreviation $[x^r]$.

A formula is known for $p(x):=\prod_{n\ge1}(1-x^n)^{-1}$. Your problem's partition function is $p(x)/p(x^2)=\prod_n(1+x^n)$. I'm not sure whether that's an even more useful result than relying on the pentagonal number theorem.

In some sense the point of a generating function can be to just view the problem in a different way. Sometimes by expression a counting problem as coefficients of an analytic object (like a generating function), one can glean information about the counting problem by studying analytic properties of the latter (a popular example is computing asymptotics). Other times it gives a ready way to prove through algebraic manipulations of the generating function things that are challenging to prove "combinatorially."

You might, for example, be able to show that the GF for the number of partitions of $n$ into odd parts is the same as the GF for the number of partitions into distinct parts. Presto, you have just proved that the two types of partitions are equinumerous.

The purpose of the expression is to translate the combinatorial question into a different medium i.e algebra, making it much easier to calculate the answer. Instead of writing out each odd partition of $i$ we can just expand the brackets of a high enough degree and get the answer. Although this is still tedious, it is easier than writing out each partition.
Generally speaking, the way to utilise such an expression is to convert each of the power series into a closed form expression (which generally will be of a certain form). In this case
$$(1+x+x^2+\dots)(1+x^3+x^6+\dots)(1+x^5+x^{10}+\dots)\dots = \prod_{k=0}^\infty {\frac{1}{(1-x^{2k+1})}}$$
Now the issue in this case is that this product gains us nothing. So, as you said, we still have to multiply out all the brackets to get the coefficients of $x^i$. (And for this reason one can ask whether this is a good enough solution.)
Having said that, with many other generating functions you will be able to get it into a closed form expression which you can then use to easily identify the contributing coefficients. For example:
$$ (1+x+x^2)^3 = \left(\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\right)^3 = (1-x)^{-3}(1-x^3)^3$$
Looking at each part separately
\begin{align}
(1-x^3)^3 &= \sum_{i=0}^3 \binom{3}{i}(-x^3)^i = \sum_{i=0}^3 \binom{3}{i}(-1)^ix^{3i}\\
(1-x)^{-3} &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{2+j}{j}x^j
\end{align}
Now if we want to calculate the $x^4$ coefficient, we know for $3i+j=4$ there will be two contributing terms $(i, j) = (0, 4)$ and $(i, j) = (1, 1)$
Then simply use the expressions from before to get the $x^4$ coefficient is
$$\binom{3}{0}\binom{6}{4} - \binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}$$

You can use generating functions to demonstrate interesting things without expanding the functions.  J.G.'s and awkward's comments on the original question point to this.
For example, suppose you wanted to compare the numbers of partitions into odd parts with the numbers of partitions into distinct parts.  There are various ways of doing this, but one is with generating functions.  You start with your generating function for the numbers of partitions into odd parts
$$(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x^3+x^6+\cdots)(1+x^5+x^{10}+\cdots)\cdots$$
treat each bracket as a geometric series
$$=\left(\frac{1}{1-x^1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-x^3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-x^5}\right)\cdots$$
introduce $(1-x^2)(1-x^4)(1-x^6)(1-x^8)(1-x^{10}) \cdots$ to the numerator and denominator
$$=\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^1}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x^2}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x^3}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^8}{1-x^4}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x^5}\right)\cdots$$
use $\frac{1-y^2}{1-y}=1+y$, and get
$$ = \left(1+x\right)\left(1+x^2\right)\left(1+x^3\right) \left(1+x^4\right)\left(1+x^5\right)\cdots$$
which is the generating function for the numbers of partitions into distinct parts.
So, for example, you can say that the number of partitions of $100$ into odd parts is equal to the number of partitions of $100$ into distinct parts. You did not need to find that there are $444793$ possibilities for each.

You can at the very least use it as a compact description for an algorithm to extract the coefficient of $x^i$. For fixed $i$, we can stop each sum in brackets once its summands are monoms of degree $>i$, and similarly we can stop the product once only brackets appear whose smallest monom that's not 1 is of degree $>i$.
So, since you've found the generating function, you now also have an $\mathcal O(i^2)$ runtime algorithm, which you can easily run by putting the truncated formula into a CAS.
